# Imported objects from Three.js json exporter are flipped or rotated

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

When I export a scene from Blender via three.js json exporter and load it into my project the objects are flipped/rotated.

I have tried:

- to use master, dev branch
- different combinations in json exporter
- to create a clean blender file and add some basic objects, had the same issue

**Example:**

Blander

[image: Blender example]

Three.js

[image: Three.js example]

Code for loading json object

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load('model/cam.json', addModelCam);

function addModelCam(object){
    scene.add(object);
}
```

Here are my export settings:

[image: threejs json export settings]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by setting rotation Z to 0 on all imported objects.

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load('model/cam.json', addModelCam);

function addModelCam(object){

    object.traverse(function(child){
        if( child.type == 'Mesh' ){
            child.rotation.z = 0;
        }
    });

    scene.add(object);
}
```